# Rendering text in turtle

Tags: turtle-graphics

How do I draw text in turtle?
This is my code so far -

```
import turtle
scr = turtle.Screen()

pen = turtle.Turtle()

scr.mainloop()
```

How do I draw text now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pen.write()` function

Here is a code example -

```
import turtle

scr = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()

message = 'Python Turtle Graphics'
font = 'Arial'
fontsize = 15
style = 'bold' # You can use 'bold', 'italic', 'overstrike' or 'underline'
align = 'center' # You can use 'center', 'left' or 'right'

pen.write(message, font= (font, fontsize, style), align= align)

# You can skip style and align
# pen.write(message, font= (font, fontsize))

scr.mainloop()
```